# How to install RBloomberg package

Tags: r, blpapi

I'm at a loss as to how to install the RBloomberg package.  The only source for the files seems to be GitHub.  The offered zip file is called blpwrapper-master.zip which embeds an rbloomberg folder.  When I try to install the zip file (in RStudio), I get an error message that it cannot open a compressed file.  I rezipped just the rbloomberg folder, but that led nowhere either.  How does one go about this?

Answer (score 3):

In general things can be installed from Github using the **devtools** package. For example:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("username/packagename")
```

I don't know who authors so **Rbloomberg**, but you can swap in the appropriate Github username in the above.

Note: Sometimes this won't work because a developer uses a non-traditional .git directory structure, but it should work in most cases. Indeed, that is the case here (as @rawr points out), where you need to use a slightly different path to point to package (which is in a subdirectory of the git repo):

```
install_github("johnlaing/blpwrapper/rbloomberg")
```

Comment: `devtools::install_github('johnlaing/blpwrapper/rbloomberg')` should do it

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to have worked.  I have to test it now on a Bloomberg terminal.